# Why does this happen when assigning names in a function?

Tags: r, data.table

Doing this:

```
x <- data.frame(a=1, b=2, c=3)

func <- function(df) {
  names(df) <- c("name1","name2","name3")
}

x<-func(x)
```

Turns `x` into the character vector of the names

but

doing this:

```
x <- data.frame(a=1, b=2, c=3)

func <- function(df) {
  names(df) <- c("name1","name2","name3")
  setDT(df)
}

x<-func(x)
```

Gives x back as a data.table. It works the same with `as.data.frame(x)` too.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is returned from the function is the last evaluated expression : `c("name1","name2","name3")`in the first function, `setDT(df)` in the second.

To update the names of the data.frame passed as an argument, just return it after update:

```
x <- data.frame(a=1, b=2, c=3)

func <- function(df) {
  names(df) <- c("name1","name2","name3")
  df # This line returns the data.frame
}

x<-func(x)
```